# Observations of the same date between hours with timestamp variable at PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I´m trying to run a select to chose some data between hours from the same date. The code below shows the idea, but it isn´t work. My datahora variable is a timestamp in the following format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss", as 2023-02-13 15:30:30. How can I run that?

```
select tr.tick, tr.cot, tr2.cot, tr2.cot-tr.cot as dif
  from tb_registros tr 
    join tb_registros tr2 on to_char(tr.datahora, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = to_char(tr2.datahora, 'yyyy-mm-dd') and to_char(tr.datahora, 'hh24:mi:ss') between '08:55:00' and '08:56:10'  and to_char(tr2.datahora, 'hh24:mi:ss') between '09:10:00' and '09:11:10'
where tick = 'ANY'
```

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data, all as text - **no images**, or better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk). Further clearly describe what you are attempting and where you are having issues. It is hard to to get a clear idea from a query that is claimed does not work. What does it do? What should it do?

Comment: Lets clear up a point many new Postgres users have. You have a column `datahora timestamp`, it **does not have any format**. It may have had a the format specified on initial entry but once stored it is an internal structure/field. It can be used for **any valid format**. Thus your expression `to_char(tr.datahora, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = to_char(tr2.datahora, 'yyyy-mm-dd')` can be reduced to `tr.datahora::date = tr2.datahora::date`. Also `to_char(tr.datahora, 'hh24:mi:ss')` reduces to `tr.datahora::time`.  See documentation [Cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-createcast.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to operate on proper date/timestamp or time values rather than strings. Assuming the column datahora is really defined as `timestamp` casting it to a `date` will remove the time part and casting it to a `time` value will remove the "day":

```
select tr.tick, tr.cot, tr2.cot, tr2.cot-tr.cot as dif
from tb_registros tr 
  join tb_registros tr2 
    on tr.datahora::date = tr2.datahora::date
   and tr.datahora::time between '08:55:00' and '08:56:10'  
   and tr2.datahora::time between '09:10:00' and '09:11:10'
where tick = 'ANY'
```

`::date` is Postgres' proprietary cast operator. If you prefer ANSI SQL, you can use `cast(... as date)` instead